# Convert cv::MAT image to CVD::Image

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, cvd

I wanted to convert a cv::MAT image to a CVD::Image but i don't know how can I do. The reason is because previously I had a CVD::Image and I transformed it to cv::MAT in order to set a ROI region in the image, and now, I need the picture in CVD.
The code used to perform it, it's the following:

```
CVD::Image<CVD::byte> Imatge_a_modificar;
Imatge_a_modificar.copy_from(mimFrameBW_workingCopy); //The image is copied from another one

int x = frameWidth/2;
int y = frameHeight/2;

CvRect sROI = cvRect(x,y, frameWidth/2, frameHeight/2);

    int xroi = sROI.x;
    int yroi = sROI.y;

cv::Mat image(frameWidth,frameHeight,CV_8UC4,Imatge_a_modificar.data());
cv::Mat imageROI(image, sROI);
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you comment or accept my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't time untill now! I'll take a look, but I've syntax problems to define the basic image.
 
CVD::BasicImage<CVD::byte> Image_2 = new BasicImage(Image1,CVD::ImageRef(Width,High),Width);

But I've an error and I don't know which one!

Comment: You don't need `new` here. Just create object on the stack, as in the original code in your question.

Comment: @Mikhail thanks for your answer, but how should I convert opencv data unsigned char to CVD::Rgb<byte> ? they are all unsigned char actually, but the compiler complain about no suitable converter. I wrote :  CVD::BasicImage<CVD::Rgb<byte> > cvd_image((CVD::Rgb<byte>)frame.data, CVD::ImageRef(frame.cols,frame.rows));

Comment: @Mikhail I just figure it out, I make opencv mat from cvd image and use copyto to set this image from another mat.  Mat cvd_image(frame.rows,frame.cols,CV_8UC3,(unsigned char*)imRGB.data());
 cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2RGB);
 frame.copyTo(cvd_image);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, use `cv::Rect`, not `CvRect`. The latter is the obsolete C type from OpenCV version 1.

Concerning your question, you need to create `CVD::Image` the same way you created `cv::Mat` - from a given bitmap buffer, where your actual pixel values are stored. To access bitmap buffer of `cv::Mat` use [`ptr()` method](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-ptr). To construct `CVD::Image` from a buffer, use the [corresponding `CVD::BasicImage` constructor](http://www.edwardrosten.com/cvd/cvd/html/classCVD_1_1BasicImage.html#ad773400d34f2da18b3d64bba3109c9cc), and then convert `CVD::BasicImage` to `CVD::Image` using [`CVD::Image::copy_from` method](http://www.edwardrosten.com/cvd/cvd/html/classCVD_1_1Image.html#a8a9b3797ecfd889ac2d097f545285fa4).